# Is there a way to share streams connections between gRPC servers

Tags: redis, grpc

I have multiple gRPC server instances run behind a load balancer and, a large number of clients each client subscribe to one of the instances.

I have a use case when I need to stream a message from server to group of clients and am wondering can I store all the client's streams in central DB ie. Redis then when I want to stream a message one of the instances will fetch all the stream connections belonging to the clients' group and use them to send a message?

Comment: Did you think-about or investigate this a bit more? thanks :) This sounds like a custom stream load balancer.